# Как в tornado получать файл в POST запросе "на лету"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, fileupload, tornado

Есть проблемка, что при отправке файла через POST-запрос в сервер на tornado, он ждет, пока клиент отправит весь файл и грузит его в оперативку. Есть ли способ как-нибудь читать отправляемый файл "на лету"? При файлах < 60MiB не особо заметно, а выше уже начинаются проблемы. Да и процесс отправки в XMLHttpRequest не отображается (нет ивентов `onprogress`).

Сам код сейчас:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

class POSTHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = "<form action='/post' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='file' name='file' multiple><input type='submit'></form>"
        self.write(form)
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        files = self.request.files['file']
        for file in files:
            with open('./files/' + file.filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(file.body)
                print('Saved file: ./files/' + file.filename)
        self.write('OK')
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/post', POSTHandler),
])
app.listen(8888)
print('Listening...')
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Есть у кого-нибудь идеи, как хотя-бы как-то улучшить положение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен обработчик аннотированный [stream_request_body](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.stream_request_body):

```
from tornado import web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

MAX_STREAMED_SIZE = 2147483648  # 2Gb
FORM_HTML = '''
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="file" type="file">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
'''

@web.stream_request_body
class UploadHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        self.fh = open('JayAndSilentBobStrikeBack.avi', 'wb')
        self.request.connection.set_max_body_size(MAX_STREAMED_SIZE)

    def get(self):
        self.write(FORM_HTML)

    def post(self):
        self.fh.close()
        self.write('upload completed')

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.fh.write(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = web.Application([
        (r'/', UploadHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```